# Converting angular string to date from datepicker

Tags: angular

I've been following along a few tutorials and now stuck at a point where by I want to display my  data value in the material datepicker.

The issue is my date is saved in an epoch:string value is not compatible to be able to display as the calendar value.

Right now I'm looking at date-adapters like everyone's been saying but how do i actually get that to work?
The adapter are just changing timestamp format to date object in which the datepicker can then get. 
Is there a way I can work on this adapter to change such that it can take something like `firestore.String`

```
@Injectable()
export class NgbDateFirestoreAdapter extends NgbDateAdapter<firestore.Timestamp> {
  /**
   * Converts Firestore TimeStamp to a NgbDateStruct
   */

  fromModel(ts: firestore.Timestamp): NgbDateStruct {
    if (ts instanceof firestore.Timestamp) {
      return {
        year: ts.toDate().getFullYear(),
        month: ts.toDate().getMonth() + 1,
        day: ts.toDate().getDate()
      };
    } else return null;
  }

  /**
   * Converts a NgbDateStruct to a Firestore TimeStamp
   */
  toModel(ngbDate: NgbDateStruct): firestore.Timestamp {
    const jsDate = new Date(
      ngbDate.year ? ngbDate.year : new Date().getFullYear(),
      ngbDate.month ? ngbDate.month - 1 : new Date().getMonth() - 1,
      ngbDate.day ? ngbDate.day : new Date().getDate(),
      12
    );
    return firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(jsDate);
  }
```

So i know that such a thing firebase. firestore. Timestamp exists but what I really need is to do the conversion of string to date object where on the datepicker input it would be something like

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" [max]="tomorrow" placeholder="Date of Birth" #dob [value]="user.date">
```

and my user.date would be that converted value from string to date.

The problem right now is that user.date comes from my `user$ | asyn` and I can't do a function to convert on ts because it would just return me an empty value

```
@Injectable()
export class NgbDateFirestoreAdapter extends NgbDateAdapter<string> {
  /**
   * Converts String to a NgbDateStruct
   */
  fromModel(ts: string): NgbDateStruct {
    var tsInt = parseInt(ts);
    var tsDate= new Date(tsInt * 1 );
      return {
        year: tsDate.getFullYear(),
        month: tsDate.getMonth() + 1,
        day: tsDate.getDate()
      };

  }

  /**
   * Converts a NgbDateStruct to a String
   */
  toModel(ngbDate: NgbDateStruct): string {
    const jsDate = new Date(
      ngbDate.year ? ngbDate.year : new Date().getFullYear(),
      ngbDate.month ? ngbDate.month - 1 : new Date().getMonth() - 1,
      ngbDate.day ? ngbDate.day : new Date().getDate(),
      12
    );
    return ngbDate.toString();
  }
}
```

This was what I have attempted with

but when I try to toggle the calendar to change date, I get an error saying

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'year' of null
>       at NgbDateFirestoreAdapter.toModel (date-adapter.service.ts:29)

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: its not so much an error but that I can't get my default string value to be displayed on my datepicker.

Comment: Have you tried `new Date(ts)`?

Comment: I have made some progress and amended the code as such